# How do I prevent page jump when using jQuery ajax tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, page-jump

I appreciate there are many questions on this topic, and I suspect some are really close to what I want, e.g.
[JQuery UI Tabs Causing Screen to "Jump"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243794/jquery-ui-tabs-causing-screen-to-jump)
[Stop jquery TABS from jumping / scrolling up when clicked on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094815/stop-jquery-tabs-from-jumping-scrolling-up-when-clicked-on)
[Jquery tabs: How do I stop the jump on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455997/jquery-tabs-how-do-i-stop-the-jump-on-click)

but I haven't found one that quite solves my problem...

I have implemented jQuery Tabs with adding and removing (similar to this: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation), but with the content of each page pulled via Ajax (similar to this: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax).

This all works fine apart from whenever I add a new tab, the browser jumps to the top of the page. This jump *only* occurs when I add a new tab - if I click between the different tabs later it does not jump at all.

I have tried using `preventDefault()` and `return false` on the anchors, but this doesn't seem to affect their behaviour. The URLs of the anchors are actual links without hashtags.

What *does* work is setting the height of the tabs container to something very large. This allows me to open tabs without the jump occurring... but it doesn't seem a very elegant solution. I should point out that the tabs are all of different heights themselves, so I can't really determine a fixed height.

Is that all there is on the topic, or is there something I might have missed?

Here is the code I am using (largely copied and pasted from the jQuery documentation):

```
var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
tabCounter = 2;
var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

function addTab(document_id, document_name) {
var label = tabTitle.val() || document_name,
id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, 'document/'+document_id).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) );
tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
tabs.tabs( "option", "active", tabCounter-1);
tabCounter++;   };
```

Comment: Can you show your tab adding code?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
tabCounter = 2;
var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

function addTab(document_id, document_name) {
  var label = tabTitle.val() || document_name,
  id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
  li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, 'document/'+document_id).replace( /#\   {label\}/g, label ) );
  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav a" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
 });
 tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
 tabs.tabs( "option", "active", tabCounter-1);
 tabCounter++;   };
```

Comment: Thank you. No joy, I'm afraid. :(